# reg ex expression to find and replace a number inside []

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="0.0" name ="sale[sales_details_attributes][1][tax]">
```

and I want to increment the [1] to [2] (i'll not know if there's a 1 or 2 or whatever, this is just for example) inside name attribute, it can be made with a regex expression but i cant make it work i tried this:

```
var name  =  $(this).attr("name").replace("[?(\d+)?\]", "[2]");
```

there's a way to get the 1 and make an increment by 1 using regex?

Comment: This is straightforward to do with just `[1]` - but are you asking for a solution that lets you increment _any_ number?

Comment: yeah but actually i'll not know what number is inside the [], that was only the explanation, i edited my question, sorry.

Comment: [`/\[\d+\]/`](https://regex101.com/r/sZ3qQ5/1) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it is to extract the number as a string, convert it to a number, and then use `toString()` in conjunction with `replace`.

```
var input_string = "sale[sales_details_attributes][3434][tax]";
var number = Number(input_string.match(/(\d+)/)[0]);
input_string.replace(number.toString(), (number+1).toString())
```

This should work for most numbers. However, it assumes there is only *one* instance of a number in your `input_string`.

Comment: yeah but actually i'll not know what number is inside the [], that was only the explanation, i edited my question, sorry.

Comment: @JoseMiguelLedón Updated to meet the new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.replace()`. ref: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
var name = "sale[sales_details_attributes][123][tax]";
var str = name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/,function(match, p1){
    return "[" + (parseInt(p1,10) + 1) + "]";
});
alert(str);
```

Comment: @JoseMiguelLedón if the answer works for you, please accept the answer so other users can easily see it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var num = 1 + (1*name.replace(/.*\[(\d+)\].*/, "$1"));
$(this).attr("name",name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, "["+num+"]"));
```